# Sitecore:PredicateBuilder or Fast Query for retrieval

Tags: performance, linq, sitecore

I have the following structure in Sitecore 7 and I need to retrieve the descendants for those updated on 2011. How do I retrieve using fast query or PredicateBuilder?

Home
- Peek
    -2009
   -2010
      -Article 1 (updated on 2011)
      -Article 2
 
Home1
-Peek1
    -2010
    -2011
       -Article 3 (updated on 2011)

Answer (score 0):

With Sitecore Fast Query you can use //* to get all descendants from a node.
To get all desendants with an update date in 2011 you can use someting like this:

```
fast:/sitecore/content//*[@__Updated >= '20110101T000000' and @__Updated < '20120101T000000']
```

In Sitecore 7 you can use the XPath Builder in the Development center.

Note it is recommend to use the Sitecore Content Search API instead of a Sitecore Fast Query when you use it in code.

Comment: Hi , when I tried to use the above script, it will also return me the folder "2011" and the "Article 3" as the folder was with updated date on 2011. Is there anyway to retrieve just the descendant only? Meaning  the last level.

Comment: Perhaps, a solution is adding a template filter, If you know which template you want or which one not, use somethings like and @@templatename = 'Article '

Comment: Also it is possible to use a wildcard in the path try somethings like /sitecore/content/*/*/*/* to get all items from a specific level